# Get current shown page in background thread

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a background thread running periodicly via timer event. I know how to invoke some things to UI thread:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => { 
    // doing stuff here...
    f_Foo("hello world");
});
```

How can I resolve in the Background thread, wich page is currently shown to user? I need for some reasons within my f_Foo a reference to the current page like here:

```
f_Foo(this, "hello world");
```

But `this` doesn´t work. Here is my declaration of f_Foo:

```
public static void f_Foo(PhoneApplicationPage pPage, string pMessage) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method that returns the Page that is currently displayed:

```
public static Page GetCurrentPage() {
    Page page;
    if (Application.Current.RootVisual is Page) {
        page = (Page)Application.Current.RootVisual;
    } else if (Application.Current.RootVisual is Frame) {
        var frame = (Frame)Application.Current.RootVisual;
        page = (Page)frame.Content;
    } else {
        page = null;
    }
    return page;
}
```

Just change the code or cast the result to PhoneApplicationPage. Oh, and you can only call it from the UI thread, but this shouldn't be a problem in your case (or in any other I've seen).

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that, if you use `NavigationService.CurrentSource` it will return you the current Uri of the page being shown to the user at that given time.

If you need to access an instance of a page, declare a static global variable of the type PhoneApplicationPage (for example in your App.xaml.cs file)

```
    public static PhoneApplicationPage CurrentPage;
```

and then, on every OnNavigatedTo method of your pages, assign the current page to that variable.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.CurrentPage = this;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

then in your method you can call:

```
    f_Foo(Application.Current.CurrentPage, "hello world");
```

Comment: No. I don´t need the Uri, I need the object.

Comment: Just edited the answer to show the object. @yasen answer seems rather good as well.